# Isn't it possible to set binary Data as cookie?

Tags: c, cookies, fastcgi

Im reading from dev/random and storing the binary data into an array.

When I write the array into my log its displayed as I want:

```
DebugLogMsg10 (pDebugLogger, sizeThreadID, "login failed->%s", UserSession.szToken);
```

But when I put it into my page build function call (the second parameter is expecting `char *` as pointer to the string which I want to be set as cookie.

```
PutMainLogIn (UsersAuthentication, UserSession.szToken, &requestFcgx);
```

If I do for example:

```
PutMainLogIn (UsersAuthentication, "testtest", &requestFcgx);
```

It is also working fine and a cookie with the value `testtest` is set.

So What is the problem?
Is it not allowed to set binary data as cookie? Or Am I missunderstanding something?

ps:
this is the structure looking like:

```
typedef struct Sesseion_s
{
    size_t sizeID;
    char szToken[TOKEN_LEN];
} Sesseion_t;
```

And this is the function prototype:

```
void PutMainLogIn (UsersAuth_t pUserData, char *szToken, FCGX_Request *Fcgx_Request)
```

Comment: By Cookie you mean an HTTP cookie?

Comment: @Stefano Sanfilippo I don't have a clou how that could help me.

Comment: HTTP cookies only accept text, so you will need to encode your binary data as text. [Base64][http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64] is a common way to do this.

Comment: @SergeyL. actually, modified Base64, because `+`, `/` and `=` cannot be used in cookies 0. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL%5Fapplications) woukld be the link.

Comment: The question I linked was actually about storing binary data in cookies, despite the generic title.